# Laravel view [auth.login] not found on server

Tags: php, authentication, laravel-5

I have a problem with my project laravel 5.7. I have developed it locally and all is well but once sent to my server online I have this error: view [auth.login] not found.

Comment: And that file exists on your server?

Comment: This question is way too broad. This might have 2374234 possible issues. You'll have to do some basic debugging to atleast limit the problem to a specific set of possible issues otherwise theres no way we can help. We aren't magicians :(. FWIW Maybe the solution here helps: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45800713/3223157

Comment: If you can't access the server and install the framework then you must upload the entire local directory, including the vendor directory which contains all the application libraries

Comment: I moved the whole project to my Debian server online and got this error so I tried to do a php artisan via ssh and again I got another error: PHP Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '=' in /var/www/clients/client1/web5 /web/gesca/base/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Arr.php on line 388

Answer (score 2):

Ran into the same problem. I noticed three things;

1. A message while booting homestead about virtualbox guest-tools being out of sync between host and guest. There could be a problem with paths. I fixed that issue with the help of this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20308794/how-to-upgrade-to-virtualbox-guest-additions-on-vm-box)
2. The ***Laravel view [auth.login] not found on server*** page displayed the path of the host machine and not of the vagrant-guest.
3. ***bootstrap/cache/config.php*** also displayed paths from the host and not the guest.

Renaming/deleting (or `artisan cache:clear`) the config.php only gave errors (Laravel Error “Unable to load the ”app“ configuration file”).

I fixed the issue by correcting the paths in config.php manually to the correct path in vagrant.

Answer (score 1):

Run following commands on your server.
it might solve your problem.

```
php artisan config:clear
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan view:clear
php artisan route:cache
php artisan optimize
```

or

```
composer dump-autoload -o
```

Comment: problem is that i can not run php artisan in my ssh project i have this error too: PHP Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '=' in /var/www/clients/client1/web5 /web/gesca/base/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Arr.php on line 388

Comment: please remove vendor folder and composer.lock file from server and run **composer install** command again.

Answer (score 0):

if you are in develop mode you can run:

`php artisan config:clear`

or if you are in product mode you can run:

`php artisan config:cache`

notice: when you use second, config clear and cache again and you force to repeat command for other changes.

Comment: This is a duplicate of the answer by Dev Ramesh.

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it